# How to collect one day record from DB?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Im trying to collect a one day record form db. The below is my query it giving error as
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer:

Code:

`start_epoctime = time.mktime(start.timetuple()) + start.microsecond * 1e-6

end_epoctime = time.mktime(end.timetuple()) + end.microsecond * 1e-6

start_epoctime = int(start_epoctime - 19800)
end_epoctime = int(end_epoctime - 19800)
postgresql :
SELECT station_number,ccu_time,where ccu_time between start_epoctime and end_epoctime`

Answer (score 0):

ccu_time is timestamp or unix time?
Try with something like:

```
SELECT station_number,ccu_time,where ccu_time between '20220301 00:00:00.000' and '20220331 23:59:59.999';
```

if ccu_time is unix time:

```
SELECT station_number,ccu_time,where ccu_time > extract(epoch from '20220301 00:00:00.000') and ccu_time < extract(epoch from '20220331 23:59:59.999');
```

Comment: ok in the query  between start_epochtime and end_epochtime. It returns the error. Instead of start and end epochtime directly pass the value  1648040400000 and 1648126799000 which execute correctly. But i dont want to use the values in query, bcz it dynamically vary whenever the program execute.

Comment: where ccu_time between '20220301 00:00:00.000' and '20220331 23:59:59.999'  --t-> the value are variable. It change if run the script after some day. How to pass dynamic variable?